# Trying to set the reference to a const reference member in class

Tags: c++, c++11

1. I want to my objectA have a const reference to objectB.
2. I want to pass that reference through a method.

i have something like this

**objectA.h**

```
private:
const objectB &__contextObjectB;
void addObjectBContext(const  objectB &contextObjectB) const;
```

**objectA.cpp**

```
void addObjectBContext(const objectB &contextObjectB) const
{
    const_cast<objectB&> (__contextObjectB) = &contextObjectB;
}
```

i get this error ***expression must be a modifiable L-value.***

I thought the whole deal with const_cast was to make lvalue expressions modifiable.

Can some one please help me?

Comment: You want a const reference that you can modify? You can't even modify a non-const reference.

Comment: I think you want `const objectB*` or `std::reference_wrapper<const objectB>`.

Comment: What you have here should work under the following conditions: 1) your `__contextObjectB` is properly initialized in the class constructor, 2) the object that `__contextObjectB` refers to is not const, 3) you remove the `&` in front of `contextObjectB` in the assignment. This assigns the object that `contextObjectB` refers to, to the object that `__contextObjectB` refers to. This that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NathanOliver explained why i can't do that, and for that thanks

@Jarod42 give me an 2 alternative.

for some reason the code below doesn't work to. Lvalue is unmodifiable

```
const objectB *__contextObjectB;
```

but seems like a good alternative.

```
std::reference_wrapper<const objectB&>
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 7):

You can only initialize a reference once.  If the reference is a class member then it is needs initialized in the constructor since that is where all class members get initialized.  That would be like

```
class Bar {};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar & b_) : b(b_) {}
private:
    Bar& b;
};
```

Once the reference has been initialized there is no way to change what it is a reference of.  If you need that sort of semantics then you will need to use some sort of pointer.

Also note that using `const_cast` to cast the `const` away of a `const` object and then modifying it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why i can't reference it more than once?
isn't there a way to use const correctness for this?

Comment: @eocamandro That is how the it is specified by the standard.  Think of a reference as an alias.  Once you create the alias it is there for life(of the reference object).

Comment: thanks, makes sense. i thought i could override that with cons_cast.

Comment: @eocamandro Nope.  One of the reasons references are this way is it allows the compiler to do some nifty optimizations.  Since a reference can never change what it is referring to the compiler could replace all calls that use the reference with the actual variable the reference refers to.  This would also mean the reference doesn't take up any space unlike a pointer.  You cannot do that with a pointer as a pointer can change what it points to at any time.

Comment: @NathanOliver, in OPs example (reference in a class) it will take up space in all implementations, and will be exactly the size of the pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA Maybe, I'm not sure in that case.  The standard says *It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage* in **[dcl.ref]**.  I am not sure if they say something in the class section if it needs storage if it is a class member.

Comment: Actually casting away const-ness is perfectly legal. It's modifying a const object through a pointer or reference to non-const object that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I fixed that.  I wasn't as explicit as I should have been.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, sure, standard says this. It's just the fact of life - the only way reference can be actually implemented as the class member is as a pointer. So when you say 'reference doesn't take up any space' you are wrong from standard point of view - like you said yourself, it's unspecified - and practical point of view, because it does take space as a class member.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't think so.  In the context of my comment I was talking about a case where the compiler swaps out all calls to the reference with the actual variable.  If it did that then there wouldn't actually be a reference.  I was not speaking of it in terms of this class example but just as a fictional example.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I find it confusing - and I know very well what is a reference :) I am afraid, for someone less familiar with the topic it would be even more confusing.

Comment: Of course at the machine level the "actual variable" is a machine address. Whereas a pointer is a machine address holding another machine address, which is the actual address of the object. So a reference is generally the same number of bytes as a pointer.